# MVVM: Do I use an event or method call to communicate between ViewModel and Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

This is a design decision but, since I am the sole developer on this project, I have no one else to ask.

I have an MVVM project and I've got a View that allows the user to add Persons to a Reservation for a Party.
There is a business rule (and that pesky "reality") that says a Person can't be added to a Reservation for the same Party. The View calls a RelayCommand to add the Person.

Since there are business rules to adding a Person I know I need to call the Model. My question is: how?

I could call a method in the Model, passing the Person, and if it returns true I can add the Person.
-- or --
I could subscribe to the PropertyChanged of the ViewModel and if a person is added check them and clear the property if they fail.

What is the better way forward?

Answer (score 6):

I disagree with @Gigi.

ViewModel should only contain presentation logic related to the ViewModel/View, like handing validations or events like clicks or formating input/output for the view. But that a Person can't be added to Reservation for the same party is probably going to be enforced everywhere, not just in your ViewModel (i.e. if you have different ViewModel which does similar action, you have to repeat your logic, which is bad).

Instead, you should have service class for handling reservations and which contains the related logic and inject this service into your ViewModel and call it's action from there.

```
// Implement interface, if you go for dependency injection or unit tests
public class PartyRegistrationService 
{   
    private RegistrationRepository registrationRepository;
    private PartyRepository partyRepository;
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    // inject the repositories here, if you use DI
    public PartyRegistrationService() 
    {
        this.registrationRepository = new RegistrationRepository();
        this.personRepository = new PersonRepository();
        this.partyRepository = new PartyRepository();
    }

    public bool RegisterPersonToParty(int personId, int partyId) 
    {
        Person person = personRepository.GetById(personId);
        Party party = partyRepository.GetById(partyId);

        // invalid person or party id
        if(person==null || party==null)
            return false;

        if(registrationRepository.GetByPerson(person)!=null) 
        {
            // person has a registration already
            return false;
        }

        // person has no registration yet
        var registration = new Registration(person, party);
        registrationRepository.Save(registration);

        return true;
    }
}
```

This way your logic is coupled inside a service class and from your ViewModel you call the services `RegisterPersonToParty` and pass the IDs to it. Ideally you use an `AsyncRelayCommand`, to avoid UI locks during repository/db operations.

Don't use such async/costly/expensive operation within your ViewModels Properties!

**edit: addition to the comment**
Depending on if you are going for rich domain or anemic domain (later one discouraged by many modern developers), there are certain type of logics which can be placed into the model and others which shouldn't.

Anemic domain is basically Model objects which don't contain any or very few (business) logic at all and all of the logic happens in the service classes.

In Rich domain you basically put business logic which is tied to a certain model into the model and keep the service layer thin.

The business logic in your requirement, shouldn't go into a certain model. The reason is, that you need more than just "Person" and "Party" data to apply the rules. You also need the Resevation Model which and you need to validate against a kind of persistence storage (SQL, local DB, Webservice, xml, whatever), so you need to access an repository to do this validations.

And you shouldn't access persistence layer form within your model, because this violates the Single Responsibility Principle (one class should be only responsible for one thing) and makes your models depend on the Repository. If you use dependency injection, you will have hell lot of a trouble to instantiate your models and injecting the repositories into it, without violating other patterns (i.e. your core should not depend on an dependency injection framework, making it hard to impossible to exchange your IoC/DI container later on).

**@AsyncRelayCommand**: 
Even if you want the user to wait until the operation is done, you should use Async operations. If you don't use, your UI will lock/freeze. This is very bad user experience.

With `AsyncRelayCommand` you can do the operation async and disable the UI container (graying out all items and preventing user input) while NOT locking your whole application. This will also prevent that your application receives an "Application not responding" message.

[image: Application not responding]

Comment: Why wouldn't I simply put it in the Model? Why create a service just for this? And I don't know that I want to do this as an async command because I need the user to wait until the logic determines that the Person can be added. Not just remove them later.

Comment: @Tseng many would disagree with your statement about events/clicks going in the ViewModel.

Comment: Updated Answer with more information. @Gigi Then these people have not fully understood the MVVM pattern yet. The VM is an additional pattern to make the ViewModels reusable (i.e. WinPhone, Silverlight, ASP.NET, WPF). Most people interpret "Model" as POCO objects (which can be fine, if you use Anemic Domain Models). Don't forget, in DDD development, ViewModel (Application/Presentation Layer) depends on Domain Layer (Business Logic and Domain Models). For very small application or prototyping you may simplify things like that, for enterprise application that's deadly.

Comment: Can you please email me? padilla (dot) henry (at) gmail.com

I'd like to figure out what the heck I'm doing. 'Cause it's not what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

Any business logic should occur in the ViewModel. Since according to the MVVM pattern the ViewModel should be isolated from the View and the Model, this makes it easy to test this business logic.

The Model is usually a lightweight data class or [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object), and it could even be automatically generated (e.g. if you're using Entity Framework database first).

So to summarise, your RelayCommand calls a method in your ViewModel, you create the Person and do your business logic checks, and if it's all good, then you save. If not, you send an error back to the UI (e.g. by setting some error text).

Comment: According to MSDN the ViewModel contains "the presentation logic and data for the view". Whereas the Model contains "business logic and data". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx

Comment: There are different interpretations... some do indeed prefer to put business logic, and it is absolutely valid. In my experience I have found that things become unnecessarily complicated when you have logic in both the M and VM layers. Depending on what "presentation logic" means, many may argue that that shouldn't be in the ViewModel at all, but in the View.

Comment: In general presentation logic is everything related to the presentation, like formating of input (i.e. receiving an iso date string as input and formating it into a DateTime type for the model itself) or doing user certain validations, i.e. can user input value into field B, when value A is empty? This is directly tied to the presentation, hence it goes into the ViewModel (i.e. disable Button, if there some fields are not filled or contain invalid data).

Comment: @Tseng there is a big difference between stuff that is "directly tied to the presentation" (View logic) and presentation state (ViewModel logic).